# Data Annotation - erro relação 1:1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, fluent-api

Estou tentando fazer relação de 1 pra 1. Aparentemente seria algo simples porém meu sistema está se perdendo nessa relação;

Não chega a dar erro, mas a relação está errada:

Model:

```
public class CieloRecorrencia
 {
       [Key]
       public int CieloRecorrenciaId { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey("CieloTokenId")]
       public int CieloTokenId { get; set; }

       public virtual CieloToken CieloToken { get; set; }
}

    public class CieloToken
    {
        [Key]
        public int CieloTokenId { get; set; }

        public virtual CieloRecorrencia CieloRecorrencia { get; set; }
    }
```

Tentei na `CieloRecorrencia` colocar:

```
[ForeignKey("CieloToken")]
public int CieloTokenId { get; set; }
```

tentei com Fluent API

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<CieloRecorrencia>()
      .HasOptional(s => s.CieloToken) // Mark Address property optional in Student entity
      .WithRequired(ad => ad.CieloRecorrencia);
```

O que acontece: ele faz a referência do

```
CieloToken.CieloTokenId = CieloRecorrencia.CieloRecorrenciaId
```

e o correto seria:

```
CieloToken.CieloTokenId = CieloRecorrencia.CieloTokenId
```

Comment: A recorrência pode ter 0 ou 1 Tokens, é isso?

Comment: isso... 
porém na pratica sempre vai ter...1-1

Comment: Na verdade na prática um tem que existir antes do outro. Acredito que seja recorrência. Então vou responder baseado nisso.

Comment: vc tem razão a lógica seria colocar o RecorrenciaId no token, visto que ele é gerado depois, vou mudar minhas model...

Comment: O princípio é o mesmo que está na resposta. Acho que não tem muito segredo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modelagem 0..1 para 1 no Entity Framework é um pouco esquisita. O correto é assim:

```
public class CieloRecorrencia
{
     [Key]
     public int CieloRecorrenciaId { get; set; }

     // Este aqui não precisa.
     // [ForeignKey("CieloTokenId")]
     // public int CieloTokenId { get; set; }

     public virtual CieloToken CieloToken { get; set; }
}

public class CieloToken
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("CieloRecorrencia")]
    public int CieloRecorrenciaId { get; set; }

    public virtual CieloRecorrencia CieloRecorrencia { get; set; }
}
```

Na verdade `CieloToken` tem uma chave primária que é estrangeira ao mesmo tempo. É a única forma de assegurar que um registro de recorrência terá apenas um Token.

Comment: não posso arrancar aquela coluna, ela vem do banco de dados..e na token eu não tenho uma coluna CieloRecorrenciaTokenId

Comment: mas se for a unica opção posso inverter onde gravar a chave...gravar no token o id da recorrencia ao invés de como faço hj, na recorrencia gravar o token..

Comment: Sim, por isso te perguntei se era a recorrência que tinha 0 ou 1 Tokens. Na verdade é o Token que pode ter 0 ou 1 recorrências.